# How to replace a character column and insert a new column with binomial presence vs. absence data instead

Tags: r, if-statement

Okay, I have done this before using the `if()` function, but I can't seem to be able to do it here.

My data looks like this:

```
sex
NA
NA
NA
hembra
hembra
NA
NA
hembra
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
macho
NA
NA
NA
```

and I would like to insert a new column to make a presence vs. absence column  so it look like this:

```
sex     Animal.present
NA      0
NA      0
NA      0
hembra  1
hembra  1
NA      0
NA      0
hembra  1
NA      0
NA      0
NA      0
NA      0
NA      0
NA      0
NA      0
macho   1
NA      0
NA      0
NA      0
```

I eventually wish to aggregate into other groups so that I may calculate the sum of certain things eg. total macho / hembra etc

Comment: Like `df$Animal.present <- ifelse(is.na(df$sex), 0, 1)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
df$Animal.present <- ifelse(is.na(df$sex),0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want totals (number of observations), you can try:

```
table(df$sex) #or
table(df$sex, useNA ="ifany")
```

Comment: Thanks -This works great! However, if I wanted to then plot the values onto a graph I would need a way to put them into my dataset. At the moment I am working with `dframe3 <- aggregate(dframe1$Animal.present,by=list(dframe1$Trip_Set),sum)`however I cannot add to original dataset as this column is shorter than the rest... The original dataset has the lat long coords for my data plotting so need to work out a way to merge them.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use

```
df$Animal.present <- (!is.na(df$sex))+0
df$Animal.present
#[1] 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```